# Get class information from file

Tags: php, php-5.3

In Java you can send `MyClass.class` as a param and use get the entire class information.
What's the equivalent in php?

I already knows about `get_object_*`, but I am looking for something more advanced.

Comment: @Bobby What was wrong with the title???

Comment: I was not able to understand the title, so I changed it to something which fits better to the question *in my opinion*. If you feel like I'm wrong, feel free to re-edit or rollback my changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP does not have [class literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2), so you are probably looking for the [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) then

> PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection API that adds the ability to reverse-engineer classes, interfaces, functions, methods and extensions. Additionally, the reflection API offers ways to retrieve doc comments for functions, classes and methods.

Example ([demo](http://codepad.org/gOjXpUNx)):

```
Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass('DateTime'));
```

There is also some functions that can give you information about a class with

- [`class_parents` — Return the parent classes of the given class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php)
- [`class_implements` — Return the interfaces which are implemented by the given class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)
- various [Classes and Object Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php)

Answer (score 0):

php also implements OOP-concept. you can do the following:

```
class MyClass {
  private $foo;
  pubclic function bar() {
    return $this->foo;
  }
}

function outer_foo($obj) {
  echo($obj->bar());
}

$myobj = new MuyClass();
outer_foo($myob);
```

Answer (score 0):

get_class — Returns the name of the class of an object
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

get_class_vars — Get the default properties of the class
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php

get_class_methods — Gets the class methods' names
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php